# Phonegap+JqueryMobile+themeroller for iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile, cordova

I am currently building an ios application with phonegap and i'm using Jquery mobile libraries. I have made a list like this:

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li>
                    <a href="#test" rel="external">
                        <h3>Nederland</h3>
                        <p>Zoek ... door heel Nederland</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

I want to have this list with some gradient colors, so i have made a theme swatch with the themeroller from jquery mobile(online app).. If i insert the theme i don't get the gradient colors,, someone had some expierence with this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My conclusion: I think phonegap doesnt have css 3 gradient possibility..